# Why would the jQuery form validator plugin start validating right away?

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

I have the following form validation logic:

```
validator = $form.validate({
  rules: {
    'comment': {
      regexp: /^[0-9a-zA-Z.,\s\/\(\)\&\'\-]*$/
    }
  }
});
```

My understanding of the jQuery validation plugin is that it does not validate until the the submit button is first clicked; after that, it validates eagerly. This is the behavior I see in my other validated forms, actually. But for some reason, in this particular case as soon as I navigate away from the `comment` input, it is validated immediately (and if I've entered invalid characters I see a red message appear beneath the input field).

Has anyone run into this before? Is there a known explanation for this behavior (and ideally a "fix" as well)?

Comment: I thought it would validate when submitted and also validates each input once it looses focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate), you'll see that the `onfocusout` option defaults to true, and does the following:

> Validate elements (except
>   checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If
>   nothing is entered, all rules are
>   skipped, except when the field was
>   already marked as invalid.

So it appears this is by design. You can set that option to false to get the behavior you want.